# Rails destroy action doesn't delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-object

I want to add service objects in to my controller. However destroy action seems didn't work properly - basically it doesn't delete anything just redirect to the page without flash message.

**user_stock_destroyer.rb**

```
class UserStocksDestroyer
  def initialize(current_user, params, flash)
    @current_user = current_user
    @params = params[:id]
    @flash = flash
  end

  def call
    stock = Stock.find(params)
    @user_stock = UserStock.where(user_id: current_user.id, stock_id: stock.id).first
    @user_stock.destroy!
    flash[:notice] = 'Stock successfully removed'
  end

  private

  attr_reader :current_user, :params, :flash
end
```

***user_stocks_controller.rb***

```
class UserStocksController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    UserStocksDestroyer.new(current_user, params, flash)
    redirect_to my_portfolio_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating the object but you're not calling `call`, the method that does the work

```
def destroy
  UserStocksDestroyer.new(current_user, params, flash).call
  redirect_to my_portfolio_path
end
```